# I cannot download torrents any more! Files I download from torrent sites have the extension .exe

Tags: downloads, bittorrent, transmission, file-format

I recently tried to download a few torrents from various sites and found that the file extension of all the files I try to download is .exe, which neither transmission nor vuze nor I know what to do with. This does not happen on all sites, but it seems to be the case on all the better/more popular ones. I am aware of the recent shift from torrent files to magnet links and have used magnet links before with no problem. I've searched and searched the web for anyone else having this problem, and the one time someone did seem to be, he was told it must be a virus, and that was as far as the conversation went. Can anyone help me and explain what's going on? Thank you!

Comment: These sites are trying to get you to download malware. Don't run these files. Avoid these sites completely.

Answer (score 2):

A number of sites are distributing torrents within a small downloader program. So you do not have to face the unspeakable horror of having a client program.

Downsides include:
Does not work on non-windows machines.
Can be used to install malware.
Cannot be used to add additional trackers / peers to a torrent you are already downloading.

I have tried, without success, to find a way to download the .exe and extract the tracker information so it can be used in a client. Either the information is encrypted, compressed or a code is used to download the torrent after you run the exe.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to execute a .exe (alias: [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)) on Linux, use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) ([Wine repository](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)).
Use unsupported Windows software by installing it in a [Virtual Machine](http://lifehacker.com/5714966/five-best-virtual-machine-applications).
**Important:** executables have the potential to infect your system, scan with [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/download.html#otherversions) and download [FOSS](http://www.osalt.com/) from your OS repository if possible.
Cracked installers may contain unwanted hidden software, **never give them sensitive informations**.

---

<sub>Comment under here if you have more questions and don't forget to press the left UP arrow and mark as favorite if I helped.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I can only suggest what you found already. It's a virus (or at least some sort of malware). Are you sure the "better/more popular ones" sites you're downloading from are the correct ones? Check the URL. Check with somebody you know, has the correct one.

Alternatively, check what you're clicking on. Many sites have other things to download. Stuff they get a commission on per install - advertising.

Make sure you're selecting the torrent file to download or magnet link. Sites can be sneaky and include things that might look like others.